# How to read YAML in list of Strings

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have a `YAML` file for my Spring app. It looks like this:

```
storages:
    file:
        local: 
          dir: file_storage
    http:
        local_host:
          url: http:*************
          client_id: *****
          secret_id: ******t
    ftp:
        ftp_server:
          path: ***********e

catalogues:
    database:
        local_database:
          host: jdbc:postgresql://l*****st:5432/ea******
          user: ***
          password: ***
          driver: org.postgresql.Driver
          maximum_pool_size: 3
    http:
        local_rest:
          url: http://localhost:1234/data

aliases:
    default_file_storage: local
    default_catalog: local_database
    a9c8662e-f4bc-4e8e-882d-310bf8e86198: local_database
    admin_catalog: local_database
    admin_storage : local
```

And I need this data as strings in `application.properties`. I download my properties from external storage at S3 from amazon. These files can be `application.properties` format or `.yml` format

```
 storages.file.local.dir=file_storage
 storages.http. local_host.url=http:*************
 storages.http. local_host.client_id=http:*************
 storages.http. local_host.secret_id=http:*************
```

and so on.

Comment: I don't see any lists defined in your yaml?

Comment: do you see YAML structure? I need to convert this structure like shown below (like, application.properties file)

Comment: I'm not sure what i can add, its basically as you have it. Without collections etc. its basically a 1:1 with all the boilerplate